# VBA code to open a file with a date in the name based on the current date

Tags: vba

Big fan of the board, but this is the first time asking my own question because I haven't been able to find anything close to what I'm looking for.

I am trying to come up with some code to open a series of files that have a month and year value in the file name, but I want to base it on the current date.  I have files all named EmployeeList YYYYMM where the year and month is for when that file was current.  I need to open each of these files in sequence for the past six months, and then copy the only tab on the file over to the file where my code is and rename the new tab with the file's YYYYMM value.

For example, if it is Sep, I want to be able to get the files with 202008, 202007, 202006, 202005, 202004, 202003 and copy the data into tabs named the same as the YYYYMM value.

I understand how to open a file based on the file name, but I can't seem to find away to open a specific file based on the date in the name.  Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something like `Format$(DateAdd("m",-1,Date), "yyyymm")` should get you started.

Comment: What have you done so far?